# checking if 2 field value does match

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I have one problem with javascript!

I want to check in user registration from if password fields match. I've written javascript code

```
function passcheck(){
    var pass = document.getElementById("pass").value;
    var passverify = document.getElementById("passverify").value;
    if (pass == passverify) {
        document.getElementById("pver").innerHTML = "<font color="green">პაროლები ემთხვევა!</font>";
    }
    else {
        document.getElementById("pver").innerHTML = "<font color="red">პაროლები არ ემთხვევა!</font>";
    }
}
```

When I run this function browser console says that `passcheck` isn't defined... can anyone help me?

**JSFiddle:** https://jsfiddle.net/giokaxo/qxsyb1s4/

Comment: See [this](https://jsfiddle.net/qxsyb1s4/1/)

Comment: what did yout changed??

Comment: You cannot use double quotes inside a tag starting with double quotes.It has to be alternate single and double quotes.

Comment: You can escape it also: `"<font color=\"red\">"`

Answer (score 5):

Firstly, in the jsFiddle you need to set the location of your code to either in the `head` or at the end of the `body`.

Secondly, you have mis-matched quotes in your strings. Try this:

```
function passcheck() {
    var pass = document.getElementById("pass").value;
    var passverify = document.getElementById("passverify").value;
    if (pass == passverify) {
        document.getElementById("pver").innerHTML = '<font color="green">პაროლები ემთხვევა!</font>';
    } else {
        document.getElementById("pver").innerHTML = '<font color="red">პაროლები არ ემთხვევა!</font>';
    }
}
```

[**Updated fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/qxsyb1s4/2/)

Here's the equivalent in jQuery:

```
$('#passverify').change(function() {
    if ($('#pass').val() == $('#passverify').val()) {
        $("#pver").html('<font color="green">პაროლები ემთხვევა!</font>');
    } else {
        $("#pver").html('<font color="red">პაროლები არ ემთხვევა!</font>');
    }
});
```

[**Example fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/qxsyb1s4/5/)

Comment: thank you very much! can you give me the code how to make same function in jquery?

Comment: Updated my answer for you.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to change this line in your code to make it work.

```
'<font color="green">პაროლები ემთხვევა!</font>';
'<font color="red">პაროლები არ ემთხვევა!</font>';
```

or

```
"<font color='green'>პაროლები ემთხვევა!</font>";
"<font color='red'>პაროლები არ ემთხვევა!</font>";
```

Using Jquery you can do the following:

```
function passcheck() {
    var pass = $("#pass").val();
    var passverify = $("#passverify").val();
    if (pass == passverify) {
        $("#pver").html('<font color="green">პაროლები ემთხვევა!</font>');
    } else {
        $("#pver").html('<font color="red">პაროლები არ ემთხვევა!</font>');
    }
}
```